# JavaScript "If Statement" not returning true value

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, foreach, boolean

I have written a simple function that checks if the provided note is valid by looping over an array and comparing values.

The code always returns `false` and I am unsure why?

When I run the code `item.split("/")[1] == note` in isolation it returns `true` (with note = "C" ) so why is my function always returning `false`?

```js
const chromatic = ["A", "A#/Bb", "B/Cb", "B#/C", "C#/Db", "D", "D#/Eb", "E", "E#/Fb", "F", "F#/Gb", "G", "G#/Ab"];

const isValidNote = (note) => {

  chromatic.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.split("/").length > 1) {

      console.log(item.split("/")[1] == note); // logs true on 3rd iteration

      if (item.split("/")[0] == note) return true;
      if (item.split("/")[1] == note) return true;
    } else if (item == note) {
      return true;
    }
  });
  return false;
}

console.log(isValidNote("C"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` ignores any value returned by its callback. Use a `for` loop instead, so that `return` will return to the caller of `isValidNote`, instead of being ignored by `forEach`:

```js
const chromatic = ["A", "A#/Bb", "B/Cb", "B#/C", "C#/Db", "D", "D#/Eb", "E", "E#/Fb", "F", "F#/Gb", "G", "G#/Ab" ];

const isValidNote = (note)=> {

    for (const item of chromatic) {
        if(item.split("/").length > 1){
            if(item.split("/")[0] == note) return true;
            if(item.split("/")[1] == note) return true;
        }
        else if(item == note){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(isValidNote("C"));
```

Or, more concisely:

```js
const chromatic = ["A", "A#/Bb", "B/Cb", "B#/C", "C#/Db", "D", "D#/Eb", "E", "E#/Fb", "F", "F#/Gb", "G", "G#/Ab" ];

const isValidNote = (note)=> {

    for (const item of chromatic) {
        const allNotes = item.split("/");
        if (allNotes.includes(note)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(isValidNote("C"));
```

Or with `.some`:

```js
const chromatic = ["A", "A#/Bb", "B/Cb", "B#/C", "C#/Db", "D", "D#/Eb", "E", "E#/Fb", "F", "F#/Gb", "G", "G#/Ab" ];

const isValidNote = note => chromatic.some(
  item => item.split("/").includes(note)
);

console.log(isValidNote("C"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Returning from the `forEach()` callback just continues the loop, it doesn't return from the `isValidNote()` function.

Use `some()` instead of `forEach()`. It returns true if any of the callbacks return true.

You can also simplify the condition inside the callback, using `includes()`.

```js
const chromatic = ["A", "A#/Bb", "B/Cb", "B#/C", "C#/Db", "D", "D#/Eb", "E", "E#/Fb", "F", "F#/Gb", "G", "G#/Ab"];

const isValidNote = note => chromatic.some(item => item.split("/").includes(note));

console.log(isValidNote("C"));
```